# Where i can find this properties panel in blender 2.79

Tags: panel

i am trying to find this properties panel in blender 2.79 but i am not able to find it, can you guys tell me that does this panel exists in blender 2.79 or not?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In 2.7 the background images don't work the same way as in 2.8. If you want to load a background image you need to open the N panel, enable *Background Images* and load your image. Then you can only change the settings you see in the N panel, you can't manually move the image in the 3D view and you don't have access to any settings in the *Properties* panel:

[image]

That said, you can create an *Empty > Image*, then you have some settings in the *Properties panel > Object Data*. It doesn't work as a *Background* or *Reference* image, but you can use it as such:

[image]